# Is there a way to use Spark to load a file in FTP using TLS

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, tls1.2, aws-glue, ftps

I am in the process of moving a python process to Spark. In python we are using ftplib to connect and download a file to a EC2 instance. Once file is downloaded, we are uploading to S3. We are transitioning to severless infrastructure and would like to load file in spark via AWS Glue and then use mulit-part upload to move it to S3. I have tried to just run the current code in a in a larger glue instance type but the machine still runs out of memory (20gb file).

old python code

```
"""
This script will get the backup file
"""

import sys
from datetime import datetime
import re

import ftplib
from retry import retry
import shutil

from tools.python.s3_functions import s3_upload
from python_scripts.get import *


def get_ftp_connector(path, user, password):
    ftp = ftplib.FTP_TLS(path)
    ftp.login(user, password)
    ftp.prot_p()
    return ftp


def get_ftp_files_list(ftp, dir):
    ftp.cwd(dir)
    files = ftp.nlst()
    print(str("-".join(files)))
    if "filecompleted.txt" not in files:
        print("Failed to find filescompleted.txt file in ftp server.")
        raise Exception("Failed to find filescompleted.txt file in ftp server.")
    regex_str = 'Backup_File_Mask_Goes_here([\d]{8}).bak'
    find_date_regex = re.compile(regex_str)
    searched = [(f, find_date_regex.match(f)) for f in files if find_date_regex.match(f)]
    searched = \
        [(file_name, datetime.strptime(regex_result.groups()[0], '%Y%m%d')) for file_name, regex_result in searched]
    searched = sorted(searched, key=lambda elem: elem[1], reverse=True)
    if not searched:
        print("Failed to find appropriate file in ftp server.")
        raise Exception("Failed to find appropriate file in ftp server.")
    return searched[0]


class FtpUploadTracker:
    size_written = 0
    total_size = 0
    last_shown_percent = "X"

    def __init__(self, total_size, bk_file):
        self.total_size = total_size
        self.bk_file = bk_file
        self.output_file = open(self.bk_file, 'wb')
        self.start_time = datetime.now()

    def handle(self, block):
        self.size_written += len(block)
        percent_complete = str(round((self.size_written / self.total_size) * 100, 1))
        self.output_file.write(block)
        time_elapsed = (datetime.now() - self.start_time).total_seconds()
        speed = round(self.size_written / (1000 * 1000 * time_elapsed), 2)
        msg = "{percent}% complete @ average speed of {speed}MB/s : total run time {minutes}m".\
            format(percent=percent_complete, speed=speed, minutes=round(time_elapsed/60))
        if time_elapsed > 600 and speed < 1:
            print("Zombie connection, failing dl.")
            raise Exception("Zombie connection, failing dl.")
        if self.last_shown_percent != percent_complete:
            self.last_shown_percent = percent_complete
            print(msg)

    def close(self):
        self.output_file.close()


@retry(tries=4, delay=300)
def retrieve_db():
    """
    This function will retrieve via FTP the backup
    :return: None
    """
    ftp = get_ftp_connector(FTP_PATH, FTP_USER, FTP_PASSWORD)
    # return back the most recent entry
    file_name, file_date = get_ftp_files_list(ftp, 'database')
    file_epoch = (file_date - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
    new_file_name = "backup_{epoch}.bak".format(epoch=str(int(file_epoch)))
    if os.path.exists(DATAFILEPATH):
        shutil.rmtree(DATAFILEPATH)
    if not os.path.exists(DATAFILEPATH):
        os.makedirs(DATAFILEPATH)
    temp_backup_file_location = os.path.join(DATAFILEPATH + new_file_name)
    print("Found file {file_name}, and downloading it to {loc}".
                format(file_name=file_name, loc=temp_backup_file_location))
    ftp_handler = FtpUploadTracker(ftp.size(file_name), temp_backup_file_location)
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file_name, ftp_handler.handle)
    ftp.quit()
    ftp_handler.close()
    print("Finished download. Uploading to S3.")
    s3_upload(DATAFILEPATH, new_file_name, bucket, "db_backup")
    os.remove(temp_backup_file_location)


def main():
    try:
        retrieve_db()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to download backup after 4 tries with error {e}.".format(e=e))
        return 1
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rtn = main()
    sys.exit(rtn)
```

New Spark Code (in progress): The username has a | character that made me encode the uri. When I run the code, I get a connection refused. I am able to use same connection info for python.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkFiles
import urllib

sc = SparkContext()
ftp_path = "ftp://Username:password@ftplocation.com/path_to_file"
file_path_clean = urllib.parse.urlencode(ftp_path, safe='|')
print(f"file_path_clean: {file_path_clean}")
sc.addFile(ftp_path)
filename = SparkFiles.get(file_path.split('/')[-1])
print(f"filename: {filename}")

rdd = sc.textFile("file://" + filename)
print("We got past rdd = sc.textFile(file:// + filename)")
rdd.take(10)
rdd.collect()
print(rdd)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to approach the problem:

1. Use a mounted file system backed by FTP and write to it from Spark.
2. Use a Spark to SFTP connector such as [spark-sftp](https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp).
3. Write the files with Spark somewhere else and copy to SFTP as a separate step. Due to the various reliability issues with SFTP and the fact that Spark leaves partial output during failed write operations, which is the path that we've taken. We write terabytes to SFTP endpoints using code that looks like the following in Scala. I hope it can be helpful for you Python work.

```
/** Defines some high-level operations for interacting with remote file protocols like FTP, SFTP, etc.
  */
trait RemoteFileOperations extends Closeable {
  var backoff: BlockingRetry.Backoff = Backoff.linear(3000)
  var retry: BlockingRetry.Retry = Retry.maxRetries(3)
  var recover: Recovery = recoverable(this)
  var ignore: Ignored = nonRecoverable

  def listFiles(path: String = ""): Seq[FInfo]

  def uploadFile(localPath: String, remoteDirectory: String): Unit

  def downloadFile(localPath: String, remotePath: String): Unit

  def deleteAll(path: String): Unit

  def connect(): Unit = {}

  def disconnect(): Unit = {}

  def reconnect(): Unit = {
    disconnect()
    connect()
  }

  override def close(): Unit = disconnect()

  /** Wraps a block of code and allows it to be retried when [[recoverable()]] conditions
    * are met. [[BlockingRetry.retry()]] is called with the var fields
    * [[backoff]], [[retry]], [[recover]], and [[ignore]], which can all be reconfigured.
    */
  def retryable[A](f: => A): A = {
    BlockingRetry.retry(retry, backoff, recover, ignore) {
      f
    }
  }

  def recoverable(fileOp: RemoteFileOperations): Recovery = {
    case (_: SocketTimeoutException, _: Int) =>
      fileOp.reconnect()
      None
  }

  def nonRecoverable: Ignored = {
    case _: UnknownHostException |
         _: SSLException |
         _: SocketException |
         _: IllegalStateException =>
  }
}

class SSHJClient(host: String, username: String, password: String) extends RemoteFileOperations {

  import net.schmizz.keepalive.KeepAliveProvider
  import net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionException
  import net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient
  import net.schmizz.sshj.transport.verification.PromiscuousVerifier
  import net.schmizz.sshj.xfer.FileSystemFile
  import net.schmizz.sshj.{DefaultConfig, SSHClient}

  override def listFiles(path: String): Seq[FInfo] = {
    import collection.JavaConverters._
    retryable {
      sftpSession(sftp => {
        sftp.ls(path).asScala
          .filter(f => f.getName != "." && f.getName != "..")
          .map(f => FInfo(f.getPath, f.getParent, f.isDirectory, f.getAttributes.getSize, f.getAttributes.getMtime))
      })
    }
  }

  override def uploadFile(localPath: String, remoteDirectory: String): Unit = {
    retryable {
      sftpSession(sftp => {
        sftp.getFileTransfer.setPreserveAttributes(false)
        sftp.put(new FileSystemFile(localPath), remoteDirectory)
      })
    }
  }

  override def downloadFile(localPath: String, remotePath: String): Unit = {
    retryable {
      sftpSession(sftp => {
        sftp.getFileTransfer.setPreserveAttributes(false)
        sftp.get(remotePath, new FileSystemFile(localPath))
      })
    }
  }

  override def deleteAll(path: String): Unit =
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("#deleteAll is unsupported for SSHJClient")

  private def sftpSession[A](f: SFTPClient => A): A = {
    val defaultConfig = new DefaultConfig()
    defaultConfig.setKeepAliveProvider(KeepAliveProvider.KEEP_ALIVE)

    val ssh = new SSHClient(defaultConfig)
    try {
      // This is equivalent to StrictHostKeyChecking=no which is disabled since we don't usually know
      // the SSH remote host key ahead of time.
      ssh.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier())
      ssh.connect(host)
      ssh.authPassword(username, password)

      val sftp = ssh.newSFTPClient()
      try {
        f(sftp)
      } finally {
        sftp.close()
      }
    } finally {
      ssh.disconnect()
    }
  }

  override def recoverable(fileOp: RemoteFileOperations): Recovery = {
    super.recoverable(fileOp).orElse {
      case (e: ConnectionException, _: Int) =>
        println(s"Recovering session from exception: $e")
        None
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed the Spring ML Sftp connector that you mention in point 2. has no proxy option (at this point in time). In my case it is needed